# When a racial trait grants me use of a spell, does it have to also become a spell I know?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits, tiefling

> **Infernal Legacy.** You know the *thaumaturgy* cantrip. Once you reach 3rd level, you can cast the *hellish rebuke* spell once per day as a 2nd-level spell. Once your reach 5th level, you can also cast the *darkness* spell once per day. Charisma is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

What I'm curious about is if the spells listed above would count against 'Spells Known' if you are playing as a spellcaster (i.e, a Warlock, Sorcerer, or Wizard.) Would these count against 'spells known' and 'spell slots' or are they separate due to them being racial traits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Spells Known is a part of the Spellcasting or Pact Magic features.  Any spells granted from other features do not count against this limit, unless explicitly stated.